# Enumerate blocks of successively equal values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, pyspark

I want to find the IDs of groups (or blocks) of trues in a Spark DataFrame. That is, I want to go from this:

```py
>>> df.show()
+---------+-----+
|timestamp| bool|
+---------+-----+
|        1|false|
|        2| true|
|        3| true|
|        4|false|
|        5| true|
|        6| true|
|        7| true|
|        8| true|
|        9|false|
|       10|false|
|       11|false|
|       12|false|
|       13|false|
|       14| true|
|       15| true|
|       16| true|
+---------+-----+
```

to this:

```py
>>> df.show()
+---------+-----+-----+
|timestamp| bool|block|
+---------+-----+-----+
|        1|false|    0|
|        2| true|    1|
|        3| true|    1|
|        4|false|    0|
|        5| true|    2|
|        6| true|    2|
|        7| true|    2|
|        8| true|    2|
|        9|false|    0|
|       10|false|    0|
|       11|false|    0|
|       12|false|    0|
|       13|false|    0|
|       14| true|    3|
|       15| true|    3|
|       16| true|    3|
+---------+-----+-----+
```

(the zeros are optional, could be Null or -1 or whatever is easier to implement)

Comment: `DataFrame` has no intrinsic order so there are no "blocks" there. You'll need some order definition, and to make it feasible on large dataset, some grouping variable. If you have both, see the solution linked below:

Comment: There is another column "timestamp" defining the order

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pyspark : Custom window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404060/pyspark-custom-window-function)

Comment: Also, please check [How to make good reproducible Apache Spark Dataframe examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915)

Comment: @prcastro did my solution help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a solution in scala, should be easy to adapt it to pyspark. Consider the following dataframe `df`:

```
+---------+-----+
|timestamp| bool|
+---------+-----+
|        1|false|
|        2| true|
|        3| true|
|        4|false|
|        5| true|
|        6| true|
|        7| true|
|        8| true|
|        9|false|
|       10|false|
|       11|false|
|       12|false|
|       13|false|
|       14| true|
|       15| true|
|       16| true|
+---------+-----+
```

then you could do:

```
df
  .withColumn("prev_bool",lag($"bool",1).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp")))
  .withColumn("block",sum(when(!$"prev_bool" and $"bool",1).otherwise(0)).over(Window.orderBy($"timestamp")))
  .drop($"prev_bool")
  .withColumn("block",when($"bool",$"block").otherwise(0))
  .show()


+---------+-----+-----+
|timestamp| bool|block|
+---------+-----+-----+
|        1|false|    0|
|        2| true|    1|
|        3| true|    1|
|        4|false|    0|
|        5| true|    2|
|        6| true|    2|
|        7| true|    2|
|        8| true|    2|
|        9|false|    0|
|       10|false|    0|
|       11|false|    0|
|       12|false|    0|
|       13|false|    0|
|       14| true|    3|
|       15| true|    3|
|       16| true|    3|
+---------+-----+-----+
```