# Dynamic window.partitionBy column in Pyspark

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

I have created two data frames. `df_stg_raw` data frame is holding duplicate records. `df_qualify` data frame is holding `meta-information` such as `partition` & `order` is based on which column. I want to remove duplicate records using `window` function available in PySpark.

```
df_stg_raw
==================================================
ACCNT_ID     NAME     SomeRandomID     TABLE_NM
==================================================
1            A          123             TblA
1            A          123             TblA
2            B          124             TblA
2            B          124             TblA
3            C          125             TblA
3            C          125             TblA

df_qualify
==================================================
TABLE_NM       QUALIFY_TXT    ODER_BY
==================================================
TblA          'ACCNT_ID'     'SomeRandomID'
```

To solve this purpose, I am cross joining two data frames. However, I am not able to pass the `paritionBy` & `orderBy` column dynamically which is present in  `df_qualify` data frame.

```
df_final = df_stg_raw.join(df_qualify, df_stg_raw.TABLE_NM == df_qualify.TABLE_NM, how = "cross") \
    .withColumn("row_num", row_number().over(window.partitionBy('**dynamic_part_col**').orderBy('**dynamic_order_col**')))
```

Comment: You wouldn't use a window function to remove duplicate records. You would use the `distinct()` method on the DataFrame. Can you give an example of the desired output, possibly adding more rows to your `df_qualify` as well?

Comment: @OliverW. With this code, I am trying to qualify records. So basically I am querying the dataset and getting the latest instance of a particular record. I found a solution and this code is now working by simply assigning partition by and order by values to variables and using variables directly in the code.